# Set::removeIf with true predicate does not delete elements

Tags: java, lombok

I have a quite simple problem, yet a very weird behaviour on which a `Set` does not delete elements on `true` predicates for some reason.

The entities (for reference only, as this does not have anything to do with the set item - or shouldn't):

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "uuid")
public abstract class Model<ID> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected ID id;

    protected UUID uuid; // Hybrid model

    @PrePersist
    private void onPersisting() {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, of = "name")
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "scope_name", columnNames = "name"))
public class Scope extends Model<Long> {

    private String name;

    public Scope(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public Scope(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, of = "name")
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "role_name", columnNames = "name"))
public class Role extends Model<Long> {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "role_scopes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scope_id"))
    private Set<Scope> scopes = new HashSet<>();

    public Role(UUID uuid, Scope... scopes) {
        this.scopes = Stream.of(scopes).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public Role(String name, Scope... scopes) {
        this.scopes = Stream.of(scopes).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The following snippet, called within a JUnit test case, does not delete the set elements (simplified for readability):

```
@Transactional
public Role create(Role role) {
    role.getScopes().removeIf(unused -> true); // <----
    return role;
}
```

For some reason, that snippet does work:

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
strings.add("FOO");
strings.add("BAR");
strings.removeIf(unused -> true);
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Is `getScopes()` returning a defensive copy?

Comment: @matt I'm debugging and yes, Role::getScopes does return a `Set` through Lombok's `@Data`.

Comment: @AndyTurner do you mind to explain?

Comment: @Henri is it, for example, returning `new HashSet<>(scopes)` rather than `scopes`?

Comment: @AndyTurner It returns the set itself. See https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok

Comment: @Henri I'm not sure what I'm meant to be looking at on that page. What happens if you invoke `role.getScopes().removeIf(unused -> true)` directly inside your unit test? Does that remove things as you'd expect? What is the return value?

Comment: @AndyTurner delomboking shows the implicit Lombok's getter (and setter) algorithm, on which you were asking me about. Calling `Set::removeIf` within the unit test does not remove the elements either.

Comment: You're using [Collectors.toSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) that isn't necessarily modifiable.

Comment: @matt that was my only guess, although calling `Set::clear` does modify the set. By the way, `Collectors.toSet` shouldn't return an unmodifiable set, as there's a function for this (`Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet`). I've ran out of assumptions.

Comment: @Henri for toSet it says there isn't a guarantee in the documentation. I would replace it with, toCollection and use a HashSet as a test.

Comment: @matt if the returned collection didn't support removal, it would throw an exception when you attempted to remove from it.

Comment: @Henri and what about the return value from `removeIf`?

Comment: @matt indeed, whats strange, though, is that changing from `Stream.of(scopes).collect(Collectors.toSet())` to `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(scopes))` on `Role` constructor, does not solve this either. Very weird.

Comment: @AndyTurner it returns true.. wtf.

Comment: How are you verifying that the items are not being removed? By using the debugger?

Comment: @Henri that would suggest that `role.getScopes() != role.getScopes()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner why would that suggest `role.getScopes() != role.getScopes()`? `Role::getScopes` returns the `scopes` memory address, not a new one. What's your point?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of overridden `equals` and `hashCode` that is done by `@Data` annotation on your `Scope` class.
If you remove it or replace with `@Getter @Setter` it will work